# Fetched data from Firestore returns duplicates

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, fetch

I am trying to fetch data from firebase firestore. The problem i have is that my fetch is returning the results x4 times. For example when i do print(name) it print the users name x4 times.

I think there may be a loop that is not working correctly?

```
// fetches and returns all conversations for the user with passed in uid
public func getAllConversations(for uid: String, completion: @escaping(Result<[Conversation], Error>) -> Void) {
    
    let CurrentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let ConversationRef = db.collection("users").document(CurrentUser!).collection("conversations").document(
        "jVymlfbpuAYQQ9Brf8SbUZ7KCGg1")
    // get the otherUserUId TO DO
    
    ConversationRef.getDocument { snapshot, error in
        if error != nil {
                print("Error connecting to database")
        } else {
            
            if let document = snapshot {
                if document.exists {
                    let data = document.data()
                    print(data)
                    
                    let conversations: [Conversation] = data!.compactMap ({ dictionary in
                        
                        guard let conversationId = data!["id"] as? String,
                              let name = data!["name"] as? String,
                              let otherUserUid = data!["other_user-uid"] as? String,
                              let latestMessage = data!["latest-message"] as? [String:Any],
                        let date = latestMessage["date"] as? String,
                        let message = latestMessage["message"] as? String,
                        let isRead = latestMessage["is-read"] as? Bool
                        else {
                        return nil
                       }
                        print(name)
                        
                        let latestMessageObject = LatestMessage(date: date, text: message, isRead: isRead)
                        
                        return Conversation(id: conversationId, name: name, otherUserUid: otherUserUid, latestMessage: latestMessageObject)

                    })
                    completion(.success(conversations))
                }
                else {
                    completion(.failure(DatabaseError.failedToFetch))
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your input to the closure is `dictionary` but inside the closure you are using `data`, I doubt that is correct.

Comment: ok so i should change dictionary to data?

Comment: How will that help? I mean that you should use the input to the closure inside the closure.

Comment: can you provide an example of what you mean

Comment: Does `print(data)` print only once?

Comment: yes, print(data) only print once, this is why i'm confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that `ConversationRef.getDocument{..}` will only Return One Specific Document, which you’re Referring here :

```
let ConversationRef = db.collection("users").document(CurrentUser!).collection("conversations").document("jVymlfbpuAYQQ9Brf8SbUZ7KCGg1”)
```

So the `let data = document.data()`
will be single [String:Any] object(in this case Single ‘Conversation’),
not the Array of Dictionaries(eg: [Conversations]).

Try doing it this way:

```
// fetches and returns all conversations for the user with passed in uid
public func getAllConversations(for uid: String, completion: @escaping(Result<Conversation, Error>) -> Void) {

    let CurrentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let ConversationRef = db.collection("users").document(CurrentUser!).collection("conversations").document(
        "jVymlfbpuAYQQ9Brf8SbUZ7KCGg1")
    // get the otherUserUId TO DO

    ConversationRef.getDocument { snapshot, error in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error connecting to database")
        } else {

            if let document = snapshot {
                if document.exists {
                    if let data = document.data() {

                        if let conversationId = data["id"] as? String,
                           let name = data["name"] as? String,
                           let otherUserUid = data["other_user-uid"] as? String,
                           let latestMessage = data["latest-message"] as? [String:Any],
                           let date = latestMessage["date"] as? String,
                           let message = latestMessage["message"] as? String,
                           let isRead = latestMessage["is-read"] as? Bool {

                            print(name)

                            let latestMessageObject = LatestMessage(date: date, text: message, isRead: isRead)
                            let conversations = Conversation(id: conversationId, name: name, otherUserUid: otherUserUid, latestMessage: latestMessageObject)

                            completion(.success(conversations))
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    completion(.failure(DatabaseError.failedToFetch))
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great, i used it as a model for changing the fetch and it is working now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
 // fetches and returns all conversations for the user with passed in uid
public func getAllConversations(for uid: String, completion: @escaping(Result<[Conversation], Error>) -> Void) {
    
    let CurrentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let ConversationRef = db.collection("users").document(CurrentUser!).collection("conversations")
    
    ConversationRef.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error in
        if error != nil {
                print("Error connecting to database")
        } else {
            guard let snap = snapshot else {
                completion(.failure(DatabaseError.failedToFetch))
                return
            }
            for document in snap.documents {
                    let data = document.data()
                print(data)
               
                    guard let conversationId = data["id"] as? String,
                          let name = data["name"] as? String,
                          let otherUserUid = data["other_user-uid"] as? String,
                          let latestMessage = data["latest-message"] as? [String:Any],
                        let date = latestMessage["date"] as? String,
                        let message = latestMessage["message"] as? String,
                        let isRead = latestMessage["is-read"] as? Bool else {
                        return
                    }
                        print(name)
                        
                        let latestMessageObject = LatestMessage(date: date, text: message, isRead: isRead)
                        
                        let conversations = [Conversation(id: conversationId, name: name, otherUserUid: otherUserUid, latestMessage: latestMessageObject)]

                    completion(.success(conversations))
            }
        }
    }
}
```